# warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float ’, but argument 2 has type ‘double ’

Tags: c, double, scanf, conversion-specifier

everyone.
I NEED HELP!
I was trying to submit this following HackerRank's challenge :
*Task
Given the meal price (base cost of a meal), tip percent (the percentage of the meal price being added as tip), and tax percent (the percentage of the meal price being added as tax) for a meal, find and print the meal's total cost. Round the result to the nearest integer.*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()

{
    int tax,tip;
    double mealc;
    
scanf("%f",&mealc);
scanf("d",&tip);
scanf("%d",&tax);
mealc = mealc+(mealc*tip/100))+(mealc*tax/100);
printf ("%d",round(mealc));

    return 0;
}
```

After compiling the code above. I always get these errors :

```
Hk2.c:33:9: warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double *’ [-Wformat=]

Hk2.c:37:11: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat=]
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: Why do you think that `scanf("%f",&mealc)` is correct, and what do you think the warning message is trying to tell you?

Comment: `%f` formats a `float` type, hence the arguments tou need to pass to `scanf` should be a float

Comment: Just use `%lf` in both instances.

Comment: `scanf("d",&tip);` you forgot a `%`

Comment: You were right to have used type `double`; it is preferable in most circumstances (rather than using `float`, which is often too imprecise).  So favor Wiliam Pursell's comment, and ignore  Rafaelplayerxd's and Tzatziki's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the warning message says the conversion specifier `%f` is designated to input values for objects of the type `float` instead of the type `double`.

To input a value for an object of the type `double` you need to use the conversion specifier `%lf`.

```
scanf("%lf",&mealc);
```

Also you have a typo in this call

```
scanf("d",&tip);
```

you need to write

```
scanf("%d",&tip);
```

And in this statement

```
mealc = mealc+(mealc*tip/100))+(mealc*tax/100);
```

there is a redundant closing parenthesis. You need to write

```
mealc = mealc+(mealc*tip/100)+(mealc*tax/100);
```

Comment: ` #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()

{
    int tax,tip;
    double mealc;
    
scanf("%lf",&mealc);
scanf("%d",&tip);
scanf("%d",&tax);
mealc = mealc+(mealc*tip/100)+(mealc*tax/100);
printf ("%f",round(mealc));

    return 0;
}
`  Yeah, it worked fine, but the result is float type. When I change the type I get the same error.

Comment: If you're worried about the last printout containing a decimal point, either use `%.0f`, or maybe `%d` along with `(int)round(mealc)`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked..

Comment: What is the difference between `"%f"` and `"%lf"`?

Comment: @Cyclone Used with the function scanf the conversion specifier %f expects a pointer to an object of the type float while the conversion specifier %lf expects a pointer to an object of the type double.

Answer (score 1):

Change mealc to float. At your second scanf tou missed a %: scanf("%d",&tip);